# Lipschitz Vectors

Tags: analysis, integration

I am trying to understand why a vector valued function where it is Lipschitz in each dimension, is also lipschitz.

In particular, I have a probability density function $p(x)= \prod p_{j}(x_{j})$ where each of the $p_{j}$ are Lipschitz functions. I am trying to understand why $p(x)$ is Lipschitz, i.e.
why is it true that
$\int_{R^{n}}|p(x-v_{1})-p(x-v_{2})|dx \leq C|v_{1}-v_{2}|,$
where $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are constant vectors?

I understand why the product of Lipschitz functions is itself Lipschitz, however, I can only seem to get it to work if the constant is the same in each dimension.

(I know that an easy out would be to use the fact that a Lipschitz function is almost everywhere differentiable and thus the needed inequality would follow by the definition of the directional derivative, but I want to avoid that as it should be more straight forward).

Thank you for the help.

Comment: On rereading the question, I am a little confused. Is $p$ vector or scalar valued? (Does the $\Pi$ mean product as in $(p_1, p_2,...)$ or multiplication as in $p_1() \cdot p_2() ...$?)

Comment: Also, if $p$ is a (scalar) pdf, then surely $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} p(x-v) dx = 1$, regardless of $v$, and hence the Lipschitz bound above is unnecessary?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question is interesting, yet it leaves some room for guessing. For example, the common definition of a function $p$ being Lipschitz is the pointwise inequality $|p(x)-p(y)|\le C|x-y|$, not the integral inequality you wrote. Are you interested in the pointwise or integral inequality? Also, the product of Lipschitz function is *not* Lipschitz in general (using the pointwise definition that I'm familiar with).

Comment: I apologize for not getting back sooner. I figured out my own question. The p was the vector while the subscripts denoted the lipschitz densities in each dimension. I apologize for the sloppiness of notation. The product denoted that as a density function it decomposes into the product of the densities in each dimension (i.e. they are all independent). However, writing out the euclidean norm gives the Lipschitz property immediately since each of the components are lipschitz functions.